# How can I transform items from a list into separate column values?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am working on creating a dataframe in python, and I am struggling on how to proceed with this problem. I am trying to analyze skincare ingredients, and I want to create a dataframe that I can regularly update with new products.

The product ingredients are stored as list items.

In the end, the dataframe should look like this:

```
product 1 = [ingredient 1, ingredient 2, ingredient 3]

           ingredient 1  ingredient 2  ingredient 3  
product 1    XYZ             XYZ          XYZ  
product 2    XYZ             XYZ          XYZ   
product 3    XYZ             XYZ          XYZ
```

The XYZ values being the items from the lists that I use. How should I tackle this? It is also important to maintain the order of the items/ingredients, and to make sure they will correctly be assigned as ingredient 1 being the first item in the list, ingredient 2 being the second item in the list, etc..

I have only found solutions where items were transformed into a list of different observations, not into column values for one single observation.

Is there a function or a method I can use to solve this issue?

Comment: your question got cut off

Comment: Is the dataframe provided in question is correct?

Comment: It should be working now (I accidentally hit submit too early)

Comment: Perhaps try putting the product names into their own row as well?

Comment: What does your original data look like?

Comment: @JakobLovern I see what you mean...but how would that solve the issue for the rest of the values in that row?

Comment: @QuangHoang  I dont have any original data unfortunately, the data would have to be made individually as a list of items (product by product), which is why I need to build the dataframe from scratch

Answer (score 2):

you can use panda data frame easily:

```
  my_data = np.array([['','ingredient1', 'ingredient2', 'ingredient3'],['product1', 45, 35, 25], ['product2', 44,34,24], ['product3', 43,33,23]])
my_data
```

which gives you:

```
array([['', 'ingredient1', 'ingredient2', 'ingredient3'],
       ['product1', '45', '35', '25'],
       ['product2', '44', '34', '24'],
       ['product3', '43', '33', '23']], dtype='|S11')
```

Then you can make a dataframe based on your data:

```
   df = pd.DataFrame(data=my_data[1:,1:],
                  index=my_data[1:,0],
                  columns=my_data[0,1:])
df
```

and produces:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend naming the first column, so that it's easier to run column operations on it, but that's a personal choice that OP has to make, not a fault of this answer.

Comment: Yes, this was actually what I was looking for! thanks

Comment: This was just an idea so you can save your data labels and indexes in separate numpy arrays and then assign them in place to the dataframe  instead of making the lists directly inside the dataframe.